# Does Power BI auto-detect the week that a date belongs to when grouping (or binning) a date field?

Tags: datetime, powerbi, binning

I need to group dates - should be a no-brainer given it's a built-in function of Power BI. The minimum value of my date field is January 01, 2024, and Power BI recognizes this.

[Power BI Grouping Pop-up shows minimum date value is January 01 2024](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lRxL7.png)

However, when I set the bin size to 7 days. It assigns January 01 2024 to the group December 31 2023 - the week it belongs to.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qydik.png)

I haven't found anything on the forum that shares my situation.

I've tried changing the data type of the field from Date/Time to Date, and vice versa but this didn't do anything.

I also tried changing the bin size and it got even weirder. When I set the bin size to 15 days, January 01 2024 is assigned to the group December 26 2023.

The problem is I don't even have data from 2023, so all visualizations using the bins will be inaccurate.

Is there any way around this?